# In Objectify, how do you load an entity by ID without knowing the parent key?

Tags: entity-framework, google-app-engine, objectify

I have an entity group in objectify, typical SomeParentClass and SomeChildClass. I want to do something like this to load an instance of SomeChildClass from the datastore.

```
ofy().load.type(SomeChildClass.class).id(idOfSomeChildClassInstace);
```

This is returning nothing found. Seems that you need to know the parent of SomeChildClass to get it from the datestore. This I know works.

```
Key<SomeChildClass> k = Key.create(someParentClass.generateKey(), SomeChildClass.class, idOfSomeChildClassInstace);
ofy().load().key(k).now;
```

What if I want to load an instance of SomeChildClass without knowing the parent, by just having the id of SomeChildClass.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot do that - the actual full identifier of an entity is the kind and id of each of its ancestors as well as it's own kind and id. That is why building the full key works, but using just the child entity id does not. Another way of looking at it that ids are only unique between siblings of the same parent.

The easiest way to solve your issue is to produce a key for your child entity, then get the 'web safe string' for it. This string contains all the information of the entity and all it's parents and can be used to fully reconstitute the full id.

Using objectify:

```
String websafeKey = Key.create(parentKey, Entity.class, id).getString();
Key<Entity> key = Key.create(websafeKey);
```

You can also do this with the low level api if you need to.

Comment: "ids are only unique between siblings of the same parent" Wow, I didn't know that! And the web safe key, that's awesome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you are saying one should store the websafeKey in a property of the child entity? (so you don't have to dig out the parent ID by having to go ahead and load the parent entity too within an API method.)

Comment: The websafe key is just a string encoding of the key, so there is no point storing it in the entity it represents. This question was 'how do you load a child without knowing the parent id', the answers is 'it's impossible'. You *could* store the id of the child in an indexed property and query for it, but that probably is a bandaid on an insufficient design. It's worth noting that you never have to load entities to create or use keys - a parent entity is not actually the same as a key parent. Keys are just coordinates - An entity isn't required to exist at each coordinate in the hierarchy.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the reply. The problem I am having is when getting or inserting Entities which have a grandparent, I need the parentId and grandparentId to do so in my API method. I was thinking then, it might be more convenient to have Entities store their websafeKey as a property. Then in my mobile app, when I want to store and Entity that has a gradparent, I could just pass in the parent's websafeKey, rather than passing in the grandparentId and parentID just to generate the key to the entity. My question is - would this be bad database design or is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: @Nick I put this into a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860123/how-to-create-api-methods-in-google-app-engine-that-have-several-decedents-ances

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the whole `Key` to be able to `get()` an entity. A child key consists of: kind, ID **and** parent key. So you need to provide all three.